# Rails 3 polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

In a Polymorphic association how should I fill in the `_type` fields while creating a record? with `Class` name? or with the table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fill it with a class name.